# How to check the integer value of a selected option with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, integer

Let's say I have a select options field like so:

```
  <select id="options">
    <option value=1>1</option>
    <option value=2>2</option>
  </select>
```

How can I check the value of the selected option?

`$("#options").value()` returns a TypeError. `$("#options").text()` returns `""` and `$("#options").val()` returns `undefined`.

How can I check the selected integer value?

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is loaded before you execute that script?

Comment: @Xufox I'm pretty sure. I can use jquery to check the values of text inputs.

Comment: `.val()` Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/vp83h8kz/ Are you reading the value before it is loaded?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Give us a reproducible snippet.

Comment: make sure to wrap your your attribute values in quotes.  eg value="1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var value = $('#options').val();
    //or
    var $('#options :selected').text();
});
```

Unless the script is executing too early your code should work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the value of the selected option

```
$("#options option:selected").val()
```

Comment: `$("#options").val()` is exactly the same.

Comment: it returns the value as a string.

Answer (score 0):

you can do one of two ways (both demo'd below, check console.log)

you can listen to the `.change()` of the `select` element you have and then find the value of the selected option

or you can go through each option and find it's corresponding values

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#options').on('change', function() {
     console.log($(this).val());
    });
    
    $('#options option').each(function() {
     console.log('option value: '+  $(this).val());
    });
});
```

```html
<select id="options">
  <option value=1>1</option>
  <option value=2>2</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the 'selected' pseudo selector on your div to specify that you want the selected option if you are looking to get the text within the selected div.

So to get the selected text would be:

```
$( "#options option:selected" ).text();
```

or if you want to get the value just use:

```
$( "#myselect" ).val();
```

You can see more info [here](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) in the jquery docs:

Comment: This is not true. What you did was get the text of the selected option. If you used .val() instead of .text() it will get the value of that selected option but you don't have to use the 'selected pseudo selector for that. You can call val() on the select element directly to get the value.